# How to find datetime 10 mins after current time?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to find out the datetime 10 mins after current time. Let's say we have

```
from datetime import datetime  
now = datetime.now()  
new_now = datetime.strptime(now, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

I want to find this `now` and `new_now` 10 minutes later. How can I do that?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/python-date-time-get-date-6-months-from-now) question. You basically just need to add a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) of 10 minutes to get the time you want.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
now_plus_10 = now + timedelta(minutes = 10)
```

Comment: while using with strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'), if i want to use GMT as well how can I do that as I am not able to get GMT using this

Comment: If you want to get the GMT, then you use utcnow() instead of now() and then add the timedelta to that in order to get the UTC time 10 minutes from now. UTC is just a different name for GMT.

Comment: One thing that could be nice to add, is that you can obtain a more "human" date/time format, using `str()`, like this: `>>> str(datetime.datetime.now()) ---> '2017-10-11 13:43:21.671497'`, if you need to store the date into a database or for any other purpose.

Comment: Note that `datetime` does not support leap seconds. https://bugs.python.org/issue23574

Answer (score 13):

```
now_plus_10m = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 10)
```

See arguments you can pass in the docs for [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Answer (score 11):

I'd add 600 to `time.time()`

```
>>> import time
>>> print time.ctime()
Wed Jun  1 13:49:09 2011
>>> future = time.time() + 600
>>> print time.ctime(future)
Wed Jun  1 13:59:15 2011
>>>
```