# How to add number to datatime variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, variables, addition

```
time_0 = datetime.time(7,00)
time_1 = datetime.time(0,30)
time_0 = time_0 + time_1

time_0 = time_0 + 0,3
time_0 = time_0 + 3
```

None of them work

How to add time_0 to time_1

How to add 30 mins to time_0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find datetime 10 mins after current time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205442/how-to-find-datetime-10-mins-after-current-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas delimit tuples or arguments in Python.

If you want to add 30 minutes to 07:00,

```
datetime.time(7) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
```