# Repeat a function every 2 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I wrote a script using opencv to read bottle level.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMaDE.jpg is an example of the project

My question is:

Every time that show the red line I need to call a two-second interval function,
but in that range there may be other red lines.
So, how can I call a function for each red line?

Comment: keep a dequeue of times you need to call the function, in the loop check if you need to call the function and remove item from dequeue. You also need a shorter exposure time and a bigger light source (flash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import datetime and have it calculate the time 2 seconds later and wait until it is (or after) that 2 seconds using the datetime.timedelta() command. [More info about timedelta here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205442/how-to-find-datetime-10-mins-after-current-time)