# Using scipy to calculate integral over time series data without function

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy

I have time-series data with y-values (around 6000 sample data) without the function in 13 minutes intervall in a csv file.
For example:
2016-02-13 00:00:00 ; 0,353
2015-02-13 00:00:13 ; 0,362
....

I want integrate over the range 9 and 14 o'clock.
How I can read the values from csv to a np.array(data) ?

The Simpson approach integrates the whole curve under y.
I have read in the doc. about my approach was:

`from scipy.integrate import simps
import numpy as np
y = np.array(data)
I = integrate.simps(y,dx=12)
print(I)`

How can i integrate in the range time (9am-2pm - 09:00:00-14:00:00) ?

Comment: Check out numpy's `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` to get your data read in.

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time handling the extra semicolon in your data with `np.loadtxt`, so here a handwritten import for your data.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num, num2date
fn="example_data.txt"

#2016-02-13 00:00:00 ; 0,353
#2015-02-13 00:00:13 ; 0,362

def dateread(x):
    return num2date(strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')(x))

tims, vals=[],[]

f=open(fn,'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    #print line
    a=line.split()
    #print a
    time=dateread(a[0]+' '+a[1])
    value= float(a[3].replace(",","."))
    tims.append(time)
    vals.append(value)

print vals
print tims

p.plot(tims,vals)
```

Output:

```
[0.353, 0.362]
[datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 13, 0, 0, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x000000000411B4E0>), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 13, 0, 0, 13, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x000000000411B4E0>)]
```

[image]

The times are now proper datetime objects, so they can be compared. To pick just the times you'd like see here : [Python time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831410/python-time-comparison)

Comment: ok but simps(y,x) causes exception. y are the values and x the timestamps

Comment: The proper reading of the timestamps was needed so you can pick and chose the times. For the integration I would set the first timestamp to time 0 and count the times in seconds. So the vector you turn over to the integration should be `real` on the x-axis. You'll be able to find plenty of answers on how to convert `datetime` to `seconds` on SO, e.g here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds