# Awaiting execution of a function in Python 3 by using datetimenow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, execution

I'm tinkering with `datetimenow()`and I'm wondering how would you go about sort of "scheduling" an execution of a function when there are 2 dates (**now** and **future** dates)?

Basically I want to keep the programming running when the date (and time) is not the same, but when it is, call some function.

What I mean is:

```
from time import sleep
import time
import datetime
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()

future = datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 15,28)



while timenow != future:
    sleep(1.0)
if timenow == future:
    '''calling some function'''
```

## Result:

Running this code only seems to keep looping although the minutes specified in `future` equals the minutes of `timenow`.

Comment: Hi, the `timenow` wouldn't change since you're assigning it as a static variable, and not incrementing it. Here both `future` and `timenow` is fixed, hence they will not change, for it to equal `you need to increment `timenow` by a second. Then only your condition will match, otherwise it's a infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two separate problems here, and you need to fix both.

---

The first problem is that you never update `timenow` in your loop. Whatever time it was when your program started, that's the value of `timenow` forever.

To fix that, you need to update it each time through the loop:

```
while timenow != future:
    sleep(1.0)
    timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
```

---

The second problem is that if `now` is, say, `2018-08-19 15:27:59.123456`, that isn't equal to `2018-08-19 15:28:00.000000`. And a second later, `2018-08-19 15:28:00.131313` *also* isn't equal to `2018-08-19 15:28:00.000000`. There's about a 1 in a million chance that you happen to hit that microsecond exactly when you're only checking once per second.

To fix that, just use `<` instead of `!=`:

```
while timenow < future:
    sleep(1.0)
    timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Now, `2018-08-19 15:27:59.123456` is less than the time you're waiting for—but `2018-08-19 15:28:00.131313` is not. So, you don't miss it.

---

While we're at it:

There's no need for that `if` statement at all. You're just testing the opposite of the `while` condition. But the only way you can get here is if the `while` condition is false, so the opposite condition will always be true, so why bother checking it?

Also, if the only thing you're using `timenow` for is in that check, you don't even need to stick it in a variable; just call `now()` directly.

So:

```
from time import sleep
import datetime

future = datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 15,28)

while datetime.datetime.now() < future:
    sleep(1.0)
'''calling some function'''
```

---

Meanwhile, there's really no reason to sleep for a second at a time. Why not just sleep once, until `future`? In some versions of Python, `sleep` can return early, so you still need a `while`loop, but you can still do this:

```
from time import sleep
import datetime

future = datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 15,28)

while datetime.datetime.now() < future:
    sleep((future - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds())
'''calling some function'''
```

Most of the time, this will sleep exactly once—occasionally maybe two or three times—instead of over and over again, so it won't, say, stop your laptop from going into low-power mode.

Also, there's a lot less chance that it'll wake up at, say, `2018-08-19 15:28:00.987654` instead of (very close to) on the second. That may not matter for your use, but if it does matter, waking up on the second is surely the one you want.

Comment: Very comprehensive and detailed. Thank you for the explanation, it helps me a lot. Also if you don't mind, would you happen to know if this (keeping the while loop running) is better than using multithreading?

Comment: @KoyaCho If you don't have anything else to do at the same time, there's no reason to use a thread. It won't really _hurt_ anything, but it's just making things more complicated for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is specify how precise you want that equality to be.
To do this you will specify a range of time that is acceptably considered to be "equal". See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831410/python-time-comparison) SO post on an example of how to do that. 
You'll end up with something as straight forward as

```
if min_future_time < timenow and timenow < max_future_time:
  # Do something.
```