# How to get Timestamp of 11PM or Any Time, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

time.time() will give current Timestamp, I just want to get timestamp of 11PM or any time.

I need this to compare when time.time() == 11PM and then perform some task.

Comment: You need to provide more details, what is `time`? Can you give an example data?

Comment: When you Google'd how to manipulate time output in Python, what did you find?

Comment: I think this has the answer to what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831410/python-time-comparison

Comment: @DanWarren Thanks, I got this

Answer (score -1):

Below script working:

```
import datetime, time

now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_to_change = now.replace(hour=23, minute=50, second=0, microsecond=0)
```